# Can you modify a Twilio call in-progress while it's still ringing?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to simulate a typical phone behaviour, where a call comes in and "rings" until someone picks it up, however I'd like to problematically control this pickup action.

Initially, when the call comes in, I throw the following TwiML at the call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Pause length="300"/>
    <Reject reason="busy"/>
</Response>
```

This delays answering the call by up to 5 minutes while the app waits for user input. The caller hears ringing during this time. If there's no input within 5 minutes, the app will disconnect the call as busy. Once the user or program has decided what to do with the call, I'd like to be able to send a new TwiML instructions.

However, when I use the method [described here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-php) to modify the call, I am given an error by Twilio that the call can't be modified as it's not in-progress.

Is there any way to send new instructions towards the call at this point to have it answered and redirected during the Pause?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the call until you answer it (in-progress), as the error message suggests. You must wait for the `<Pause length="300"/>` to complete, as it is the first verb in the returned TwiML and the call will remained unanswered until it completes and a TwiML Verb which answers the call is reached.

[TwiML™ Voice: Pause](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pause)